# How to make a request from Redoc swagger spec

Tags: swagger-ui

Is it possible to make a request like you would in a swagger.io html page in the redoc API page? Or is [redoc](http://swagger.io/redoc-openapi-powered-documentation/) just to display the details of the API?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm the author of ReDoc.

At the moment there is no API console functionality implemented in ReDoc. But we have this in the [roadmap](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc#roadmap).

Hopefully this will be implemented in 4-5months

update: https://redoc.ly/docs/api-reference-docs/console-overview/

From the docs:

> warning
>
> The Try it feature is not available in Redoc's "community edition".
> You will need access to Redocly's Reference docs or Developer portal
> to use the Try it feature.

Comment: Swagger already has a console so sticking with that.

Comment: Well, that's fairly disappointing. We may have to move on to swagger-ui (which is a shame because ReDoc does offer a nicer looking page.)

Answer (score 8):

### Update April 2023:

I found this as the best alternative https://rapidocweb.com/
It's not just better than Redoc, but also (IMHO) better than their paid version.

It's extremely customizable.

### Update Oct 2020:

As per maintainer: https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/issues/53#issuecomment-576377856
Open source version of ReDoc wont have API console functionality.

If you want you can get the paid version.
As for me, I will go find an alternative :)

Comment: Did you find an alternative? I'm looking for a standalone version like redoc has that dynamically loads the doc by consuming the spec url.

Comment: @storesource no, sorry. We might just have to make our own. There is a fork of redoc that has the api console, but havent tried it yet. Ill use this post to update if i find anything interesting out there. Please let me know if you do as well.

Comment: Here is some fork with initial console support: https://github.com/raha1923/redoc/pull/1

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

Comment: I updated my answer with a new option!! @storesource

Answer (score 7):

After wasted few days, I understand redoc only have making request feature on their commercial version, so I switch to its alternatives.

If you use react, you can try openapi-react, similar to redoc, but it has function to issue http request.

Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-react